# Does Effect veiler negate Decode Talker's ability to negate effect veiler?

Tags: yu-gi-oh

1. Decode talker is on the field
2. Effect veiler is played during your opponents main phase 1
3. Does Decode talker lose the ability to tribute a card and negate effect veiler?

http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Decode_Talker

- Gains 500 ATK for each monster it points to. When your opponent activates a card or effect that targets a card(s) you control (Quick Effect): You can Tribute 1 monster this card points to; negate the activation, and if you do, destroy that card.

http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Effect_Veiler

- During your opponent's Main Phase (Quick Effect): You can send this card from your hand to the GY, then target 1 Effect Monster your opponent controls; that face-up monster your opponent controls has its effects negated until the end of this turn.

Comment: if you had 2 veilers in hand you could always activate another one'

Comment: Technically yes and no. Because if you use Effect Veiler's effect before it points to any monsters, then it can't use it's effect. Because Decode Talker's effect is great, but it comes with a price. Because in order to activate it's effect, it must tribute a monster that it points to. But if it does point to a monster it can. But however there is a way that even if Effect Veiler doesn't work, there can be something useful. If you use it, your opponent must choose whether to risk losing a monster or risk not being able to use it's effect, both unfavorable options if you ask me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this scenario you can chain Decode Talkers effect to Effect Veilers Activation to negate the activation. So the effect of Effect Veiler doesn't matter to Decode at this point.

The Different here is when an effect is activated and when it resolves and how a chain is build and resolved.
You can look on the wikia for informations

http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Chain

Or in the official rulebook, which also comes which each Structure Deck on page 40

http://www.yugioh-card.com/uk/rulebook/Rulebook_v9_en.pdf

Answer (score 0):

If Decode Talker is pointing to a monster, then yes, there shouldn't be a reason it cannot negate Effect Veiler if you chose to.